# Continues run of an applet in Java, How?

Tags: java, applet

I am having some issues with having an applet i created in java run continiusly, it ends when its run its course and i want it to just go back to the start.

It's my very first applet so i am a little proud ;) jk. Its a simple "whats your name?" and "Hello " + name; But here as its done and i press the little ok button it all ends to my sadness. I just want it to as me again what my name is :/

If someone could redirect me towards what i need to read to get what i am missing i would be really greatfull.

Thanks!!

Comment: 22 questions and 4 accepted. improve it first and then post some code also.

Comment: what you have tried Could you show them ?